# Unable to set custom colours to Navigation bar items iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using the below code in my **AppDelegate** to set the colours for the Navigation Bar items. It works when I use the default colours (Step 1) and doesn't work when I use custom colours (Step 2).

Could someone please suggest how I could fix this ?

**Step1: Works**

```
// Set navigation bar, background color
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor   = UIColor.red
```

**Step 2: Doesn't Work**

```
// Set navigation bar, background color
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor   = UIColor(red: 41,  green: 150, blue: 204,  alpha: 1)
```

Here is my extension for my UIColor, implemented in one of my styles.swift file

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(_ r: Double,_ g: Double,_ b: Double,_ a: Double) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r/255), green: CGFloat(g/255), blue: CGFloat(b/255), alpha: CGFloat(a))
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `255` with `255.0`

Comment: divide to 255 will make result be either 0 or 1, is `Int` type, you have to make it Double, Float or CGFloat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    extension UIColor {
    static func rgb( red : CGFloat, green : CGFloat, blue : CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Step 2 :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor   = UIColor.rgb(41,150,204)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the default initialiser and not the one implemented in the extension :

Remove the params in your code like so :

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor   = UIColor(41, 150, 204,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

UIColor's `init` takes `CGFloat` parameters, and `CGFloat` is a typedef for `Double`. Try to change your extension to accept `Int` as parameters instead of `Double`

Answer (score 0):

Your extension is wrong. You have to divide by a float. As of now you are dividing by an Int so you are probably just getting 0 or 1.

It should be "r/255.0" etc...

EDIT: And as others have pointed out, you are not using your extension.

It should be

```
UIColor(41, 150, 204, 1)
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually correctly using your extension.

To use it, call like this,

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor   = UIColor(41,150,204,1)
```

When you use underscore `_` character for method names in the method definition, you have to omit method names when calling it.

Answer (score -1):

On your UIColor Extension, do you have a need to define a convenience init? or can't you just use:

```
public func rgba(_ r:Int, _ g:Int, _ b:Int, _ a:CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: a)
}
```